# The reply to this interaction has not been sent or deffered

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So I've been working on a radio command on my discord bot but It keeps on getting errors like this and I was wondering if someone can assist me with the command

The error:

```
C:\Users\Matthew\OneDrive\Documents\Moria Calliope\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\InteractionResponses.js:149
    if (!this.deferred && !this.replied) throw new Error(ErrorCodes.InteractionNotReplied);
                                               ^

Error [InteractionNotReplied]: The reply to this interaction has not been sent or deferred.
    at SelectMenuInteraction.editReply (C:\Users\Matthew\OneDrive\Documents\Moria Calliope\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\InteractionResponses.js:149:48)
    at InteractionCollector.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Matthew\OneDrive\Documents\Moria Calliope\interactions\slash\utilities\radio.js:90:22)
    at InteractionCollector.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at InteractionCollector.handleCollect (C:\Users\Matthew\OneDrive\Documents\Moria Calliope\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\Collector.js:119:14)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  code: 'InteractionNotReplied'
}
```

Here is the main code:

```
const {
    ActionRowBuilder,
    SelectMenuBuilder,
    SlashCommandBuilder,
    ActionRow,
} = require("discord.js");
const {
    joinVoiceChannel,
    createAudioResource,
    createAudioPlayer,
} = require("@discordjs/voice");
const radioAssets = require("../../../Util/radioChannels.json");
module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName("radio")
        .setDescription(" | Listen to the radio!"),
    async execute(interaction) {
        await interaction.deferReply({ ephemeral: true });
        const channel = interaction.member.voice.channel;

        if (!channel) {
            return interaction.reply({
                content: "You need to join a voice channel to do this!",
            });
        }

        // Get the radio meta from the json file that has been declared
        const getRadioChannel = radioAssets.channel.map((rad) => ({
            // Then, re-formatted to label and value mapped object
            label: rad.nativeName,
            value: rad.name,
        }));

        // Make some select menus..
        const radioMenu = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(
            new SelectMenuBuilder()
                .setCustomId("radioList")
                .setPlaceholder("Select a radio channel!")
                // Set it as the options, so the user can choose.
                .addOptions(getRadioChannel)
        );
        const msg = await interaction.editReply({
            content: "Please select one of the Radio channel that are listed below!",
            components: [radioMenu],
            fetchReply: true,
        });

        // Make some filter..
        const filter = (i) => {
            if (interaction.user.id !== i.user.id || i.customId !== "radioList") {
                i.followUp({
                    content: "This menu is not for you!",
                    ephemeral: true,
                });
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        };

        // Collectors..
        const collector = msg.createMessageComponentCollector({
            filter,
            time: 30000,
        });
        collector.on("collect", async (interaction) => {
            // Find a radio name that match to the value that we set up before.
            const findRadio = radioAssets.channel.find(
                (rad) => rad.name === interaction.values.toString()
            );

            const player = createAudioPlayer();
            // If we got the radio correctly, then get the radio uri.
            const resource = createAudioResource(findRadio.uri);

            // Make it connect to the voice channel
            let connection = joinVoiceChannel({
                guildId: interaction.guild.id,
                channelId: channel.id,
                adapterCreator: interaction.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
                selfDeaf: true,
                selfMute: false,
            });

            // And this should play the audio
            player.play(resource);
            connection.subscribe(player);

            // You can remove this, but msg "This interaction failed" should appeared, so if you keep this, that msg shouldn't appear
            await interaction.editReply({
                content:
                    "Radio has started successfully! Please do not undeafen me so I cannot hear your conversations while playing my music.",
                ephemeral: true,
            });

            // And you are done.
            await interaction.channel
                .send({
                    content: `Started playing **${findRadio.nativeName}** in <#${channel.id}>`,
                })
                // Make the bot set suppressed to false if the initial command being used in stage channel
                // KNOWN BUG: if the bot moved to stage channel it does not make the suppress to false.
                .then((msg) => msg.guild.me.voice.setSuppressed(false))
                // Error known because the user are not in a stage channel
                // "You are only allowed to do this in stage channels"
                .catch((err) => console.err(err));
        });
    },
};
```

Basically it keeps on saying that I haven't sent or deferred anything. I'm new to slash commands please help me-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After `async execute(interaction)` you actually defer a reply by using `await interaction.deferReply({ ephemeral: true });`, so that's what you want to remove!

Comment: Thanks, but whenever I remove it, it says: InteractionNotReplied

Comment: @Fawnino from what I can see, you are trying to edit a reply, even tho you didn't reply yet, so instead of editing maybe try to just reply?

Comment: oh okie will do